# The Facebook SDK for PHP v4 の 認証時、 getSessionFromRedirect で止まる

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

[The Facebook SDK for PHP v4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0) において Oauth 認証を利用してプロフィール（名前、メールアドレス）などを取得したいと思っております。しかし `getLoginUrl` で生成した URL に飛び、自分自身のファイルに callback すると `getSessionFromRedirect` でエラーも吐かずに止まってしまいます。( echo デバックでの確認）

参考ブログ記事: 「[Facebook API v4でプロフィールを取得する](http://gokexn.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-44.html)」

ほかのサイトのコードも試したのですがうまく行きませんでした。考えられる原因があれば教えていただきたいです。

**実行環境**

- CentOS6.4
- facebook-php-sdk-v4 4.0.15
- PHP 5.4.37

Comment: getSessionFromRedirectでエラーを吐かずに止まるという情報だけで判断するのは難しいので、
getSessionFromRedirectがどんな値を返しているかを追記してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

手元にて確認しました。
上記のURLのコードは問題なく動きます。

過去にFacebookのOAuthのログイン周りがおかしくなった際、動作が何も起きなかったり、突如例外を吐いたりしました。
アプリを作りなおして、別のAppID,Secretを発行するか、時間経過で直った事があります。

他のサイトのコードもうまくいかないという事は、そのFacebookアプリ自体が原因な可能性があります。
アプリを作り直す事は簡単に解決できる可能性のある方法なので、試してみてください。

**実行環境**

- OSX Yosemite
- facebook-php-sdk-v4 4.0.15
- PHP 5.4.36
- FaceBookアプリCallback先 localhost

Comment: サーバー側の設定のミスでした。
error_logを確認して原因を調べるのが方法を調べることが大切だとわかりました！ありがとうございました。